# Xcode modifies current CoreData model version at every launch

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

I'm using Xcode 4.6 to work on a project which uses CoreData. The data model is now at version 13 and uses lightweight migration.

My problem: At every launch Xcode seems to modify the PROJECT.xcdatamodeld/.xccurrentversion file to be set to version 1. I noticed that the modified file is automatically added to the GIT index. The changes made to this file are NOT reflected by the GUI of Xcode which tells me that my model's current version is 13. This problem started at some point during the development process (maybe at model version 7) and persists even for new model versions. The strange thing about it that even different Xcode installations on different computers show this behavior for this project. I included a screenshot of the changes made to the file.

My workaround is to reset the changes to this file at every launch of Xcode using GIT but it's very annoying. Someone got an idea how to solve this? Seems like a bug in Xcode.

[image: Changes made to the .xccurrentversion file at every launch]

Comment: Using Xcode 6.2 and I'm still having this issue.  But the accepted answer below didn't work because I don't have a duplicate section.

Comment: I think I solved it!  I had included a link to the xcdatamodeld in another project (used to populate the initial CoreData store), but it was missing the individual version files.  I just removed the xcdatamodeld from the project and dragged it over from the source project again and this time everything appears to have come over correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved: The problem was an old entry in the project.pbxproj file (Open PROJECT.xcodeproj with right click -> "Show package content"). I deleted the section as shown in my screenshot and everything is running fine.

[image: Screenshot showing the section to delete]

Comment: It seems like this is still an issue ... after 4 years and at least two major version bumps for Xcode

Comment: Nope. Not for me. After 5 years, XCode10 still changes automatically for the wrong data model version.

Answer (score 0):

For us, what **really** solved the problem was:

- select the data model in the Project navigator
- select the configuration (`Default` for us)
- in the Inspector -> File inspector change the data model version by clicking the small folder icon (below Location, find the red box in the screenshot below) and selection the correct `.xcdatamodel` file (notice no "d" at the end of the file). See the example where I've already changed from the version "1" (`Notifications.xcdatamodel`) to version "2" (`Notifications 2.xcdatamodel` visible in the screenshot).

[image]